# JavaScript Function Only Working Sometimes With Same Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got the following bit of code (using JQuery) that I've written for a project. The idea is to have a function that you can attach to an element within an "item" div and it will return the id of that div. In this case, the div id would be item-[some item primary key value]. This function works probably 9/10 times, but every once in a while it will get to the else else case and return false. I've verified through the console that the input for selector is the exact same JQuery $() item in both the success and fail cases.

I'm relatively new to JavaScript, so there may be something obvious I'm missing, but this is some really unusual behavior.

```
var recursionCounter = 0;
function getElementID(selector, recursionDepth, searchString){
    console.log(selector);
    var elementID = selector.attr("id");
    if(elementID === undefined){
        elementID = "";
    }
    if(elementID.indexOf(searchString) !== -1){
        elementID = elementID.split("-")[1];
        return elementID;
    } else {
        if(recursionCounter < recursionDepth){
            recursionCounter++;
            return getElementID(selector.parent(), recursionDepth, searchString);
        } else {
            recursionCounter = 0;
            alert("The element clicked does not have an associated key.");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example of code that calls this function, for some context.

```
$(document).on("click", ".edit-pencil-item", function(event) {
  //Use helper function to get the id of the surrounding div then pass it to the function
  var itemID = getElementID($(this), 10, "item-");
  jsEditItem(itemID);
  return false;
});
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: The html might help too.

Comment: You could replace most of that with a call to `.closest()` probably.

Comment: Why would such a question get down-votes? What is missing or unclear or incomplete etc etc here?

Comment: It could be because you are not resetting your `recursionCounter` after you find your element ID and return it. Try `recursionCounter = 0` before `return elementID;`

Comment: What Pointy said.  If your edit-pencil-item is directly surrounded by the div you want you can use $(this).parent().attr('id') or if it is indirectly surrounded you can use $(this).closest('div').attr('id') .  Or maybe even $(this).closest('[id^="item-"]').attr('id')

Comment: @Pointy This may be just what I was looking for before. Thanks!

Comment: @ShaneHaw That was exactly it. I don't know how I missed that. It would just keep adding up, fail, and then reset. Thank-you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the encapsulating element of your clicked element, and you know it should have an id starting with "item-"  you should be able to do something along the lines of

```
$(this).closest('[id^="item-"]').attr('id')
```

Which says find this elements closest parent that has an id starting with "item-" and tell me its id.